# Magento trigger shipping by custom option

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have a downloadable product in the Magento catalog. This have a custom option attached to let the user decide if he want to receive the physical copy of the product.

The problem is that magento disable shipping address for every downloadable product. I searched a lot for a solution to this and the general suggestion is to create one downloadable product and one normal product but I really don't want to do that as I have tons of products and it would be hell to manage the catalog.

Can anyone tell me if this is in fact possible to do in magento and if it is possible, point me in the right direction on how to apply the modification to the shipping handling classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to overwrite the `isVirtual()` function within:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Product/Type.php
```

When the custom option is selected (and only then), it should behave like:

```
public function isVirtual($product = null)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Checkout will then act like with normal products and request for shipping options.